Compound trigger
I have a trigger on the CLIENTES table and I need to increment the clientes.MODIFICACIONES field each time an update is performed on a record of the table
I created the following trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MODIFICACIONES
FOR UPDATE OR INSERT ON CLIENTES 
COMPOUND TRIGGER 
TYPE TYPE_CLIENTE_INFO IS RECORD ( 
COD_CLIENTE    CLIENTES.cod_cliente%TYPE, 
MODIFICACIONES CLIENTES.MODIFICACIONES%TYPE 
);
TYPE TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE IS TABLE OF TYPE_CLIENTE_INFO INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
V_TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE;

AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
    V_TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE(V_TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE.COUNT + 1).COD_CLIENTE := :NEW.COD_CLIENTE;
    V_TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE(V_TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE.COUNT).MODIFICACIONES := NVL(:NEW.MODIFICACIONES, 0);
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1 .. V_TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE.COUNT LOOP
        UPDATE CLIENTES C
        SET C.MODIFICACIONES = V_TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE(I).MODIFICACIONES + 1
        WHERE C.COD_CLIENTE = V_TABLE_TYPE_CLIENTE(I).COD_CLIENTE;
    END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END MODIFICACIONES;

UPDATE CLIENTES C
SET TELEFONO = '12345'
WHERE C.COD_CLIENTE = 'C0011';
When I update the table, I get error ORA-00036.
I expect the CLIENTES.MODIFICACIONES field to be incremented by 1 when an update is performed
for example:
Before an update is performed on the CLIENTES table, a record looks like this
COD_CLIENTE|NOMBRES|DISTRITO|Telefono|Modificaciones
C0011      |Hernan |Lince   |12345   |0
and after the update, the same record should look like this
COD_CLIENTE|NOMBRES|DISTRITO|Telefono|Modificaciones
C0011      |Hernan |Lince   |12345   |1
